# Is there a better way to sort this items?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I already have my code working, but I believe that could be improved.

This is basically the main part, where I re-order a list of items;

```
const splice = ($index, item, direction) => {
    $scope.list.splice($index, 1);
    $scope.list.map((i) => {
        if (i.order === item.order) {
            i.order = direction === 'up' ? i.order + 1 : i.order - 1;
        }
        return i;
    });
    $scope.list.push(item);         
    $scope.list.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a.order < b.order) return -1;
        if(a.order > b.order) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}
```

You can see the entire code here:
https://codepen.io/rochapablo/pen/jpGKKa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it confusing that a function named `splice` does something different from what it commonly does.
This function does too many things:

- It removes one item from a list
- It modifies the `order` field of some items in the list
- It adds an item to the list
- It sorts the list

A more descriptive name would be better, and one that avoids confusion with existing concepts.

Instead of splicing one item and then adding one,
it seems you could just replace the item at the index after the mapping step,
which would be simple, and probably perform better.

The sort function can be written simpler as `(a, b) => a.order - b.order`